# Mapping and isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a vector space of dimension n and consider any basis B. Show that the mapping $v  → (v)_B$ is an isomorphism from V to $R^n$, i.e. a linear transformation that is one-to-one and onto.

How do I prove that in the most efficient way?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Should I say that v and $R^n$ have the same dimension n so it is an isomorphism?